# How would I have an image reveal a youtube video, on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

On my website I have a youtube video whose thumbnail does not look good, so I would like to replace it with a picture.  I have not found any way to do this on google so I would like to have the an image that when the user hovers over it, a specified youtube video is revealed.  When that video is revealed the user can click play and then the image will not re-appear while the video is playing.  I am currently using php/cakephp, html, css, and javascript.

Is there anyway I can do this?  Current I am using a carousel to hide the ugly thumbnail but it does not look the greatest since it is leaving shadows when the bigger youtube video is not showing.

Comment: I'm not going to be able to help you because I am currently not that versed in php but I do know anyone that does try to help you will want to see your code or the snippet in question to help you or to see what you have already done/tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change the youtube thumbnail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYphhwCatLE, but if its another video, From that point on set another div to take up the same place whose opacity changes to 0 once hovered or viceversa whichever works. so to put it in code

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 100%(or whatever)">
     <video style="opacity: 0; z-index: 10;" width="320" height="200">
         <source whatever >
     </video>
     <div style="position: absolute; top:0; width: 320px; height: 200px;">//or could be an image
     </div>
</div>
```

After that setting video:hover to opacity 0 or you could use display. Its really up to you. This is the direction I would go in at least. setting the container to position relative, restricts the elements inside to the limits of itself so position absolute is "relative" to the bottom and top of container.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful.